# Javascript: How to apply "../" in URLs with RegExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is a good RegExp in order to remove any "`../`" in URL by removing it's related parents?

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/main-directory/sub-directory/../index.html
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/main-directory/index.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use this RegEx in a loop:

```
[^\/]+\/\.\.\/
```

## Function

Then you can use this:

```
function path(string, t) {
    return (t = string.replace(/[^\/]+\/\.\.\//,'')) !== string ? path(t) : t
}
```

This is even better if you are using the latest version of JavaScript **ES6**:

```
var path = (s,t) => (t = s.replace(/[^\/]+\/\.\.\//,'')) != s ? path(s) : s;
```

## Alternative

If you don't like functions:

```
while ( string != (string = string.replace(/[^\/]+\/\.\.\//,'')));
```

Comment: Declare first `t` variable in **strict mode**, or just use a second parameter as help `var path = (s,t) => (t = s.replace(/[^\/]+\/\.\.\//,'')) != s ? path(s) : s;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a regex like this to remove parent:

```
[^\/]*?\/\.\.\/
```

or use below regex

```
(.*?)[^\/]*?\/\.\.\/(.*)
```

And use substitutions `$1$2`:

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/qU6wU2/1)

Comment: Thanx, but it's not work for multiple ../, for example: **http://www.example.com/main-directory/sub-directory/../../index.html**

Comment: For multiple use of `../` I suggest you to use a loop over results instead of finding a regex ;).